# User Permission After Registration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my database i have this

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('admin')->nullable();
            $table->string('usertype')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Which means in my form i have this

```
<select name="usertype">
                      <option>Select Usertype</option>

                      <option value="1">Landlord</option>
                      <option value="2">Agent</option>
                      <option value="3">Tenant</option>

                    </select>
```

Users can select the type of user they are.
I have this in my RegisterController

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'usertype' => $data['usertype'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

When a user which is landlord registers it takes them to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard`

How can i make the content different for each users i.e
1. I want landlord to be able to just add property
2. I want tenant to be able to edit profile, see properties they have bought.
3. I want agent to able to add property like landlord.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **Laravel Policies**. Example if you have a PropertyController, you can have a PropertyPolicy with the method:

```
/**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return $user->usertype == 'Landlord';
    }
```

And in the view, you can do something like:

```
@can('create', $property)
    // link to create property
@endcan
```

learn more about **Laravel Policies** at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: i did this in view ```@can('create', $apartmentType)
          <li class="{{ 'admin-posts' == request()->path() ? 'active' : ''}} dropdown">
            <a href="/admin-posts">
              <i class="now-ui-icons education_atom"></i>
              <p>All Apartments</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          @endcan```` and apartmentTypeController did this ```public function create(User $user)
    {
        $apartmenttype = ApartmentType::find($id);
        return $user->usertype == '1';
    }``` i got this error `Undefined variable: apartmentType ```

Comment: The way it works is that, the controller handles the usual CRUD functionality. Policies allows you create the authorization logic for each model/resources which are registered in the `AuthServiceProvider` you can then validate using blade view directives like `can`. You should go through the docs to fully understand how this works.